# Yii - textfield length validation working wrong when i enter spacial characters

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2, yii-components

I have a city field. which allows all characters. I have written a rule which is not allowed to enter more than 50 characters. UI level it is working perfectly. But php throws an max length error even though i have enter less than 50 characters. I have found the problem but i don't know how to solve it.

for an example if i enter spacial characters it converts into html entities before validation. e.g. & converts to `&amp;`. so length property working wrong. please do help. thanks in advance.

```
 Input: Karur 1##@!@@!@#@#@#&&&&&&& 
 During Validation: Karur 1##@!@@!@#@#@#&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;
```

Comment: [According to PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Please show your controller and model code so we could be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

u can set rules in model to allow characters only.
so it is not allowed any symbol,

I think your question is related to this answer....

```
array(
            'username',
            'match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/[^a-zA-Z_-]/',
            'message' => 'Invalid characters in username.',
        ),
```